# Battery charging thresholds being ignored by tlp on Thinkpad E50

Tags: linux, laptop, battery, thinkpad

I have a Thinkpad Edge E50 running MX Linux 21.2.1 which I'm trying to configure for optimum battery life. If I'm interpreting the man page correctly it should be sufficient to use the command `tlp setcharge 40 50` followed by `tlp start` to activate charging when the battery level drops to 40% and stop charging at 50% but this isn't happening for me. Charging always starts regardless of the charge level and continues up to 100%,

I've also tried setting the thresholds for both BAT0 and BAT1 in /etc/tlp.conf but that didn't have any effect.

I've read the section 'Why is my battery charged up to 100%' in the [tlp FAQ](https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/battery.html#why-is-my-battery-charged-up-to-100-ignoring-the-charge-thresholds)  and the required kernel modules appear to be loaded

```
root@thinkpad:~# lsmod | grep tp_smapi
tp_smapi               45056  0
thinkpad_ec            16384  1 tp_smapi
```

tlp-stat doesn't report any problems

```
root@thinkpad:~# tlp-stat -b
--- TLP 1.5.0 --------------------------------------------

+++ Battery Care
Plugin: thinkpad-legacy
Supported features: charge thresholds, recalibration
Driver usage:
* tp-smapi (tp_smapi) = active (status, charge thresholds, recalibration)
Parameter value ranges:
* START_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0/1:  2..96(default)
* STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0/1:   6..100(default)

+++ ThinkPad Battery Status: BAT1 (Ultrabay / Slice / Replaceable)
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT1/manufacturer               = (not available)
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT1/model                      = (not available)
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT1/manufacture_date           = (not available)
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT1/first_use_date             = (not available)
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT1/cycle_count                = (not available)
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT1/temperature                =      0 [°C]
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT1/design_capacity            = (not available) 
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT1/last_full_capacity         = (not available) 
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT1/remaining_capacity         = (not available) 
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT1/remaining_percent          = (not available) 
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT1/remaining_running_time_now = (not available) 
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT1/remaining_charging_time    = (not available) 
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT1/power_now                  = (not available) 
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT1/power_avg                  = (not available) 
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT1/state                      = none

/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT1/start_charge_thresh        =     40 [%]
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT1/stop_charge_thresh         =     39 [%]
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT1/force_discharge            =      0
```

I note that tlp-stat shows values for BAT1 where I would have expected BAT0 because this laptop only has one battery, could this be relevant. It also reports the wrong value (39) for the stop threshold which was set to 40 but the FAQ mentions that this is normal for the Edge series and the charge thresholds should work as configured.

Comment: Can you (1) update BIOS and (2) load up a Windows System temporarily and set Tthreshold with Lenovo Vantage.   That will likely work.

Comment: @John. Updating the BIOS might be a possibility but I'm wary of doing that on this old laptop. Lenovo's support site doesn't recognise the full model number or serial number of this device. I've already bricked another old laptop due to a failed BIOS update so I don't want to risk turning this one into a doorstop by flashing an inappropriate BIOS. If my problem was a serious show stopper I'd give it a try but if I don't manage to fix this issue I'll just live with it.

Answer (score 2):

The command `tlp setcharge` is not the one you want, as it only has effect
until the next boot.

You should for a permanent setting change the charging parameters
in the config file `/etc/tlp.conf`.
Something like the following might help:

```
# Main / Internal battery (values in %)
START_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0=40
STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0=50
```

References :

- [Battery Care](https://linrunner.de/tlp/settings/battery.html)
- An example config file for ThinkPad :
  https://gist.github.com/pauloromeira/787c75d83777098453f5c2ed7eafa42a

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be due to a bug in the firmware. I haven't found a cure but I have come up with a useable workaround.

After issuing the command `tlp setcharge 40 50` the charge thresholds are set in /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT**1** despite the laptop only having one battery. The thresholds in /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0 remain unchanged. It appears that the bug causes charging to start when the battery level drops below the threshold for BAT**0** and stop when it reaches the threshold for BAT**1**.

My workaround is to manually store the desired thresholds in both the BAT0 and BAT1 subdirectories after which charging starts and stops at the expected values, despite the stored values for the start threshold being wrongly displayed as the value of the stop threshold plus one.

It's possible that a BIOS upgrade might fix the problem but, as I said in an earlier comment, I'm reluctant to upgrade the BIOS on this laptop and there's nothing in Lenovo's release notes for newer releases specifically relating to battery firmware.